# Display random simpson quotes

Tags: react.js, typescript, jsx

I'm new to Typescript though I've got a few years experience with plain Javascript. This is the first full program I've built in Typescript using Next.js. I'm just curious about areas where I can improve especially with the interfaces.

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

interface QuoteProps {
  image?: string, quote?: string, character?: string
}

interface QuoteArray {
  image: string, quote: string, character: string
}

function QuoteComponent(props: QuoteProps){
  return(
    <div>
      <img src={props.image} />
      <p>{props.quote}</p>
      <span>{props.character}</span>
    </div>
  )
}

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [quoteData, setQuoteData] = useState<QuoteArray>()
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [filterString, setFilterString] = useState('')

  const handleFetch = () => {
    let url;

    filterString.length > 1 ? 
      url = 'https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes?character='+filterString : 
      url = 'https://thesimpsonsquoteapi.glitch.me/quotes'

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => setQuoteData(data['0']))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))
  }

  //We load a random quote on page load
  useEffect(() => {
    handleFetch()
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      {
        loading ?
        <p>Loading...</p> :
        <>
          <QuoteComponent 
            image={quoteData?.image} 
            quote={quoteData?.quote} 
            character={quoteData?.character} 
          />
          <input placeholder='Filter by character name' onChange={(e) => { setFilterString(e.target.value) }} />
          <button onClick={handleFetch}>New quote</button>
        </>
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1):

Since both QuoteArray and QuoteProps are actually the same (Quoteprops is an optional subset of QuoteArray ), you can use the Partial keyword.

```
interface QuoteArray {
  image: string, 
  quote: string, 
  character: string
}

function QuoteComponent(props: Partial<QuoteArray>){...}
```

[Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

Partial constructs a Type with all properties of Type set to optional. This utility will return a Type that represents all subsets of a given Type.

You can also export the interface so it becomes reusable in other components. Whenever this need arises, the question of creating a types file depends on what you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- `QuoteComponent` doesn't need to take optional properties and guard against their absence. Typescript allows you to be more definitive in your coding. Instead, make them required. You'll be able to write just a single guard in the caller.
- Even better, because Typescript can enforce a certain shape to a structured property, the component could just accept a single object (what you are calling `QuoteArray`) with required properties. This makes calling it easier. It removes all the details from the page class, which is nice.
- Some of the naming could be cleaned up: QuoteArray isn't an Array; it's also called "quote data"... unifying this would be nice.
- I would probably call `handleFetch` something different, as it's not "handling" a fetch... it's just doing one. It's handling a "new quote request", so I'd use that as the name. If you want to name it based on what it does, it's just `fetchNewQuote` (also good), which would be the onClick handler of  the button.
- It looks like `loading` is only set to `true` the first time the component renders, so it can probably be replaced by just looking for the presence of the quote data... although this is a little nitpicky... you may want to do a `setLoading` call within your `useEffect`-- although this gets complicated to get the timing worked out.
- I think Next.js has a different (server-side) way of loading data like this... but this will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

What I like to do is have a dedicated folder for types. Where I can reuse it all throughout my project.

Although with your interface you did kind of write the same code twice.

You can just extend the other interface to reuse it.

- https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-extend-interface/

Hope this helped!